# Service stops/exits when chef-client exits

Tags: service, weblogic, chef-infra

I am making a call to a service in Chef to start the weblogic nodemanager. We have an init.d script (`service nodemanager start`) that makes the following call to nodemanager:

```
su weblogic -c /opt/ora/mw/wlserver_10.3/server/bin/startNodeManager.sh &
```

We are running a simple test recipe as follows:

```
service "nodemanager" do
  action :start
end
```

We can see that indeed the node manager script is being called/started but as soon as the chef-client run completes, it kills the node manager script. We've tried seemingly every combination of **daemon** and **nohup** but to no avail. Any ideas why the script gets killed when chef-client exits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using "&" means it brings the current command run in background as child process but still attached to the current process. which means once the parent process started by chef-client exits, all child processes will get SIGNUP. So the node manager script is not killed. You can verify this by using `ps aux` to check the columns *PID* and *PPID*.

The ideal fix is using `daemon` to run your node manager under a dedicated user/group without tty in your init.d script.

A quick fix is using `nohup`:

```
su nohup weblogic -c /opt/ora/mw/wlserver_10.3/server/bin/startNodeManager.sh &>/dev/null &
```

Comment: Worked for me, just had to swap the nohup to be at the front. The `/dev/null` seemed to be the key. I had tried daemon and nohup previously